# How do I make all instances in Java do something

Tags: java, static-methods

I am trying to create a static method that moves all instances to the origin, but I can't use a static method on instance variables (like xPosition and yPosition).

Would I have to loop through all of the instances, or is there a way to do this with a static method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you calling the "origin" of an instance ? Have you an example ?

Comment: If the question is: Is there a way to retrieve all instances of a given class? The answer is no unless you stored manually all the instances used in a Collection

Comment: I am painting to a canvas and using (0,0) as the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that you have all the instances of your class, I would prevent allowing to create the instances directly by making the constructors `private` and enforcing calling a `static` method to **create and publish** the instance, something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    /**
     * Thread-safe collection used to store all existing instances
     */
    private static final Collection<MyClass> INSTANCES = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    private MyClass() {}

    public static MyClass newInstance() {
        // Create the instance
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        // Publish the instance
        INSTANCES.add(instance);
        return instance;
    }

    public static void release(MyClass instance) {
        //Un-publish my instance
        INSTANCES.remove(instance);
    }

    public static void releaseAll(Predicate<MyClass> predicate) {
        //Un-publish all instances that match with the predicate
        INSTANCES.stream().filter(predicate).forEach(INSTANCES::remove);
    }

    public static void apply(Consumer<MyClass> consumer) {
        // Execute some code for each instance
        INSTANCES.stream().forEach(consumer);
    }
}
```

**Then your code will be:**

```
// Create my instance
MyClass myClass = MyClass.newInstance();
// Execute some code here
...
// Release the instance once the work is over to prevent a memory leak
MyClass.release(myClass);
...
// Execute some code on all instances
// Here it will print all instances
MyClass.apply(System.out::println);
...
// Release all instances that match with a given test
MyClass.releaseAll(myClass -> <Some Test Here>);
```

Comment: Most useful insight! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a static method if you have a static registry of all the instances.

```
class YourClass {
  static List<YourClass> instances = new ArrayList<>();

  YourClass() {
    instances.add(this);  // Yuk! Unsafe publication.
  }

  static void moveAll() {
    for (YourClass instance : instances) {
      // Do something to instance.
    }
  }
}
```

But I'd recommend you don't do that, but instead have a non-static registry class:

```
class YourClassRegistry {
  List<YourClass> instances = new ArrayList<>();

  void add(YourClass instance) {
    instances.add(instance);
  }

  void moveAll() {
    for (YourClass instance : instances) {
      // Do something to instance.
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
YourClassRegistry registry = new YourClassRegistry();
registry.add(new YourClass());
registry.add(new YourClass());
registry.add(new YourClass());

registry.moveAll();
```

This allows you to have separate groups of "instances", that you can move separately.

Global mutable state (like the static version of the registry) is a pain in the neck, reduces testability, requires more care with respect to thread safety etc.

Comment: hum not really thread-safe

Comment: It can be made thread safe. TBH, that's a secondary concern here.

Comment: to be less error prone, for me you should not allow to create an instance of YourClass otherwise you could miss calling add. For now, YourClassRegistry is only somehow a Collection of YourClass nothing more, it should go further, don't you agree?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto except for the `moveAll` method, and the lack of all the other methods in the `Collection` interface. Readers are free to go further as they require.